# GitHub API issue - listing starred repos

Tags: json, api, curl, github, repository

I'm trying to list all of the repos that I'm currently starring, and I do:

```
curl -u 'user' https://api.github.com/user/starred
```

And it only gives me a subset of the repos I'm starring, not all of them. I've don't know if this is an API issue, or a repo issue, but I can't seem to determine what the criteria is for GitHub returning only a part of my starred repos.

Help!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

GitHub uses paging on their API results. See the response `Link` headers described in the API docs: http://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination and http://developer.github.com/v3/activity/starring/#list-repositories-being-starred

Anyway, to get the rest of the results, use `https://api.github.com/users/:user/starred?page=X&per_page=Y`, where X is the number of the page, and Y is the page size (max 100).

Comment: The `:` in `:user` is incorrect. But your URI works great if you just remove it: [`https://api.github.com/users/hobson/starred?page=1&per_page=10000`](https://api.github.com/users/hobson/starred?page=1&per_page=10000)

Comment: Thanks. Couldn't find this in the api docs for the life of me.

Comment: @hobs :id is a convention for a variable id url part

Comment: thanks @caub I wasn't familiar with that convention, though I have seen `/<user_id>/` or `/$user_id/` or `/{user_id}/`